# remove /add class on window resize jquery

Tags: jquery, removeclass, window-resize

I'm trying to use the following code to remove a class on window resize for a menu in a responsive theme, but it won't work.

```
 (function() {
var $window = $(window),
    $ul = $('ul.nav');

$window.resize(function(){
    if ($window.width() < 979) {
        return $ul.addClass('float');
    }else{

    $ul.removeClass('float')};
}).trigger('resize');
});
```

The .float isn't defined with the .css. It's just there if the submenu (generated dynamically in an admin area) get too large to fit in the container.

Here's the code for generating the "float-effect" when the submenu is to large

```
   $('.float > li.dropdown > a + ul').each(function(index, element) {
  // IE6 & IE7 Fixes
  if ($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version == 7 || $.browser.version == 6)) {
  var category = $(element).find('a');
  var columns = $(element).find('ul').length;

  $(element).css('width', (columns * 143) + 'px');
$(element).find('ul').css('float', 'left');
    }       

    var menu = $('.float').offset();
    var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();

    i = (dropdown.left + $(this).outerWidth()) - (menu.left +      $('.float').outerWidth());

    if (i > 0) {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + (i + 5) + 'px');
    }
});
```

Here's a part of the beginning of the menu code

```
    <?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <div class="menu">
<ul class="nav float">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>">
    <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
     .
     .
     .
     .
     ecc.
```

Any other ideas to remove/ add the class ".float" on window resizing?
Thanks in advance for any tip.

**EDIT**

After trying a little bit, i've found an alternative solution with the .css query

```
  @media (max-width: 979px)
```

Now it's working, but i still can't understand why the jQuery resize isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it will help.

```
 var $window = $(window),
     $ul = $('ul.nav');

 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($window.width() < 979) {
       $ul.addClass('float');
   }else{

    $ul.removeClass('float')};
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good solution to me, did you try putting your code inside a document.ready function? like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

var $window = $(window),
    $ul = $('ul.nav');

$window.resize(function(){
    if ($window.width() < 979) {
        return $ul.addClass('float');
    }else{

```
$html.removeClass('float')};
```

}).trigger('resize');

});

Comment: There is already a  `$(document).ready(function () {` at the very beginning of  the  external .js file, which calls most of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the dollar in front of:

```
(function() {
```

is equivalent to document.ready.

Is $html defined somewhere before this code is executed? Otherwise, maybe you intended it to be $ul?

The return in:

```
return $ul.addClass('float');
```

is not required, although this is not an error.

Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: sorry: `$html` should be `$ul`. But it doesn't change too much. Still not working and no errors in the console :-(.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not actually calling your function. You can have multiple document ready handlers, so as suggested by others, simply add `$` in front of your function to turn it into a document ready handler:

```js
$(function() {
  ...
});
```

Other options are to change it into a named function and calling it from your existing document ready handler or executing it as an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```js
(function() {
  ...
}());
```